# PostgreSql search query

Tags: spring, postgresql

I have a user model, in which the json field of products, in which there is a transaction id, this transaction should be unique for all users, try to make unique here not suitable, need to go through all users and in json check this id field and if the number of matches is greater 0, then issue an error, so, I can not write this query, in which direction to move?

```
for (PurshasedProduct product : user.getPurshasedProducts()) {
        if (!purchased.contains(product.getProductId())) {

            // TODO check another users bought
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            String var = product.getTransactionReceipt();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select username from user WHERE  info -> 'purshasedProducts' ->> 'transactionReceipt' = [[var]]");
            if (rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount() > 0) {

            }
            dbUser.getPurshasedProducts().add(product);
        }
    }
```

I can't pass a var variable that changes every time

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: i add some code